# Save object from template

Tags: python, html, django, web

Im creating a music website. In this website, I would like to add the functionality of favorites so users could add songs to their favorite lists.

I have done everything but I don't know how to save it. Here is my code:

## models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):

    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

## views.py

```
def song_detail(request,song_id):
    song = Song.objects.get(pk=song_id)
    favorite = song.is_favorite = True
    return render(request, 'song_detail.html', {'favorite':favorite})
```

## song_detail.html

```
<button onclick="{{favorite}}">Favourite</button>
```

While playing with the python shell, I found the problem:
Let s be the created song with pk=1,

```
d = Song.objects.get(pk=1)
d.is_favorite=True
d.save()
y = Song.objects.filter(is_favorite=True)
print(y)
->s
```

The problem was after making a song's is_favorite = True, we need to save it. But I don't know how to implement it in the code such that when a user clicks the button the boolean field changes to true. Thank you.

Comment: How can we help without seeing the code?

Comment: Edited: Added the codes.

Comment: The browser would need to trigger an ajax `POST` request which sets this attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself!

I changed the values of favorite from views to song.update(is_favorite=True).